# A word for the thing that adds the last piece to something, making it complete?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Each period has a start and an end. If we observe a period as a pair and from one pair either the start or the end is missing, how would we call something, that adds the missing part, making the period `whole` or `complete`. `period completer` or `period finisher` just doesn't sound right to me. Maybe `period adder`? In German, I would use the word `Ergänzer`.

Comment: With my limited German understand, does Ergänzer mean "whole maker"? I'm trying to ascertain whether you're looking for a word specific to **timespans** or any form of completion (e.g. the last person to join a party, the final piece to a puzzle, the last job for today, ...)

Comment: Something like the *ultimate* or *final* member of the set, or unit of time?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean period as "a span of time" or in the musical sense?  Based on what you have said, the best word I can think of is "complement".

It can be:

- something that fills up, completes, or makes perfect
- one of two mutually completing parts :  counterpart

See the full definition here:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complement

Comment: @k-christine-scarpinatto in mean it as in `span of time`. But I think complement is a good term for the actual missing part, like the start could be a complement to the end. I am looking of a word, which add the complement for the original item.

Comment: "Counterpart"  could refer to either member of a pair.   Is that any closer to what you need?

Comment: @AlexBG: Complement does usually imply that there are **two** elements in total. That's not always literally the case, though. A third employee can be said to complement the earlier team of two employees, but that is in essence comparing the past state to the new state (= two things). Complement also implies a **difference** (in a way that the pieces nicely fit together, a healthy balance). From your description I would assume that if you have to make 250 breads, and you already have made 249 breads, that the 250th bread is also an "ergänzer"? That isn't a correct use for "complement", imo.

Comment: Please note that I am looking for the term that describes the person or the thing that adds the last element, not the last element itself. So if we assume the laat element is complement, the it must be something like complementor or complement adder.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are getting at.  There is the word "capper", as in " the capper to the campaign rally was an appearance by the candidate himself" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capper).